# How do I set up a metatable to inherit from another metatable while at the same time changing the userdata to another type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, lua, lua-userdata

This is something I want to do in C++ using the Lua C API.

I'm trying to figure out a good way to make userdata derive from a base userdata object.

I want to be able to do this:

```
local item = me:GetCurrentItem()
print(item:GetPos())
```

instead of:

```
local item = me:GetCurrentItem()
print(item:GetBaseObject():GetPos())
```

In these examples, me:GetCurrentItem() returns userdata with some functions, but it lacks the base functions which item:GetBaseObject() returns.

I'm binding Lua in the Crysis Wars SDK for learning purposes. The SDK provides an interface to the base entity which is a struct. The IItem struct (me:GetCurrentItem()) is the same. 
Since these are structs I can't cast them to the base struct or call its base functions. I have to use the IEntity *GetEntity() function.

I've tried chaning the self pointer in __index but it causes the local variable "item" to become "entity" which is kinda obvious, but I want it to revert back after calling the GetPos function, which seems illogical somehow.

Does anyone have a good solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious solution would be defining an item:GetPos() function that does the redirect.

```
function Item:GetPos()
  return self:GetBaseObject():GetPos()
end
```

Where Item is the item's metatable.

This is as efficient as making changes on the metatable, and less problematic.

EDIT: I can help you a bit with the repetitiveness too.

You can implement the following two functions:

```
function delegate(klass, methodName, memberName)
  klass[methodName] = function(self, ...)
    local member = self[memberName]
    if type(member) == 'function' then member = self[memberName](self) end
    return member[methodName](member, ...)
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
delegate(Item, 'GetPos', 'GetBaseObject')
```

That single line whould do the same as the `Item:GetPos` 3-line definition above.

If you need to repeat this a lot, you can optimize it further with this other function:

```
function delegateMany(klass, methodNames, memberName)
  for _,methodName in ipairs(methodNames) do
    delegateMethod(klass, methodName, memberName)
  end
end
```

Which should allow you to do:

```
deletageMany(Item, {'GetPost', 'SetPos', 'GetColor', 'SetColor'}, 'GetBaseObject')
```

I haven't tested any of these functions, so beware of bugs. They should work with both "gotten properties" (`self:GetSomething()` as well as simple accesses `self.something`). The code assumes that you would always use ':' to invoke the delegated methods, so `self` is added when needed.

Comment: I thought of doing this if there would be no good way. It would be a very repetitive task to add the same functions again in all the classes since the base entity has a lot of functions I'm going to use.

Comment: Maybe I just need to realize this _is_ the proper way.

Comment: @CapsAdmin Repetitive code is never a good thing. I've added some code that should allow you to do what you want in a cleaner way. Let me know if you have any issues with it.

Comment: I wanted to do this in C++, but doing it in Lua doesn't seem like a bad idea after all.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the Lua implementation, and if later on it's identified as a bottleneck, implement it in C++. Chances are that it won't be necessary though. Also, thanks for accepting my answer!